# upload file using xhr2 on IE 10 work only for text files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, html, internet-explorer-10

I try to use xhr2 to upload files .
its work fine in FF , chrome but when I try it on IE10 its send only Text files no image no rar.

my script code

```
$("#uploader").click(function () {
alert("upload");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileUploader");
var file = fileInput.files[0];

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("files", file);
alert(file.size);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:7128/FileManager/uplader.ashx');
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
xhr.send(fd);
```

});

Comment: looks fine to me.  you'll have to provide more information and troubleshooting evidence

Comment: the script is work fine in FF and chrome  but in IE 10 its only send Text files EX .txt .xml .config but when i try to upload image or rar file no files sent to http://localhost:7128/FileManager/uplader.ashx no exception or error just the context.Request.Files is empty , did it work for you ?

Comment: There is no doubt that your issue either lies in your server side environment, or there is some code you are not listing here that is responsible for this problem. You will have to do some work troubleshooting this your self and report things such as errors that appear in the javascript console, raw request and response data, etc etc